# HTML form problems

Tags: html

Here is my code :

```
<body onload="read()">
<div class="style1" id="Layer3">
<textarea name="textarea" cols="30" rows="5" id="msg" ></textarea>
</div>
<div id="Layer1">Hello World!<img src="body.jpg" width="842" height="559" /></div>
<div id="Layer2"><img src="close.jpg" alt="Go Online/Offline" name="close" width="63"    height="64" id="close" OnClick="action()"/></div>
<div id="Layer4">
<input type="button" value="Send Line" onclick="sendline()" /></div>
<div id="Layer6" style="color:white;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:16px;width:500px; height:400px; overflow:auto;"></div>
</body>
```

The problem that I'm facing is that there is no cursor appearing inside the textbox! Nor does the submit button seem to be clickable :S (the above code is a sub part of my whole page's code)
Any guesses as to why these error are cropping up ?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not showing the CSS behind these things so it's impossible to say what the problem may be. The best thing would be a live link.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have float (or absolute positioned) div with transparent background that blocks mouse clicks

-- update

your #Layer6 has position:absolute css attribute, it hides your inputs behind itself
using "position:absolute" to create page template is bad practice. but anyway you can try to put "Layer6" div before "Layer1" div to solve problem or play with "z-index" attributes in all your "layers"

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. @Anant: Give the `.style1` a higher z-index.(>5)

Comment: Umm, that solves the problem,but now when i press submit,the PC freezes!  WHy is this happening ?

Comment: @Anant: could you please update your http://techknowlegy.iblogger.org/index.htm with latest version to have a look

Comment: i'm not sure about post request in sendline() function, maybe you want to send value - not html element, try something like this: 
var message = $("#msg").val();
$("#msg").val(" ");
$.post("chat.php",{msg:message});

Comment: i wanted to send the text in the textarea:msg,so what's wrong with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Just some thoughts
1. Where is your `<form>` tag?
2. A `textarea` is not a `textbox`. Try `<input type="text"...>`
3. I tested this on firefox, and I saw a cursor in the text area...

**Edit:** You might want to tag this question as `jquery` as well, because I notice from your source because that's what you are using.